# awk: next is illegal inside a function

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a short shell function to convert human readable byte units into an integer of bytes, so, e.g.,

10m to 10000000
4kb to 4000
1kib to 1024
2gib to 2147483648

Here is the code:

```
dehumanise() {
    for v in "$@"
    do
        echo $v | awk \
        'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}
        function printpower(n,b,p) {printf "%u\n", n*b^p; next}
        /[0-9]$/{print $1;next};
        /K(B)?$/{    printpower($1, 10,  3)};
        /M(B)?$/{    printpower($1, 10,  6)};
        /G(B)?$/{    printpower($1, 10,  9)};
        /T(B)?$/{    printpower($1, 10, 12)};
        /Ki(B)?$/{printpower($1,  2, 10)};
        /Mi(B)?$/{printpower($1,  2, 20)};
        /Gi(B)?$/{printpower($1,  2, 30)};
        /Ti(B)?$/{printpower($1,  2, 40)}'
    done
}
```

I found the code also somewhere on the internet and I am not so confident with awk. The function worked fine until I re-installed my MacBook a few days ago. Now it throws an error

> awk: next is illegal inside a function at source line 2 in function printpower
>    context is
>                   function printpower(n,b,p) {printf "%u\n", n*b^p; >>>  next} <<<

As far as I understand, next is used in awk to directly end the record. Hence in this case it would end the awk statement as it only has one input.

I tried to move the next statement simply behind printpower(...);next.
But this causes the function to give no output at all.

Could someone please help me repair the awk statement?

# awk --version

> awk version 20121220

macOS awk version

## solved

The no output thing was probably an issue with the macOS awk version. I installed and replaced it with gawk:

```
brew install gawk
brew link --overwrite gawk
```

Now it works fine without the next statement.

Comment: What version of awk are you using?

Comment: Also you don't need next anywhere anyway.

Comment: awk --version simply gives a build number 20121220 (maybe a date)

Comment: Yeah, personally i would just install GNU awk.

Comment: No, do not add the solution in the question. Instead, add an answer yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software design fundamentals - avoid inversion of control. In this case you don't want some subordinate function suddenly taking charge of your whole processing control flow and **IT** deciding "screw you all, **I'm** deciding to jump to the next record". So yes, don't put `next` inside a function! Having said that, POSIX doesn't say you cannot use next in a function but neither does it explicitly say you can so some awk implementations (apparently the one you are using) have decided to disallow it while gawk and some other awks allow it.

You also have gawk-specific code in your script (`IGNORECASE`) so it will ONLY work with gawk anyway.

Here's how to really write your script to work in any awk:

```
awk '
    { $0=tolower($0); b=p=0 }
    /[0-9]$/ { b =  1; p =  1 }
    /kb?$/   { b = 10; p =  3 }
    /mb?$/   { b = 10; p =  6 }
    /gb?$/   { b = 10; p =  9 }
    /tb?$/   { b = 10; p = 12 }
    /kib$/   { b =  2; p = 10 }
    /mib$/   { b =  2; p = 20 }
    /gib$/   { b =  2; p = 30 }
    /tib$/   { b =  2; p = 40 }
    p { printf "%u\n", $2*b^p }
'
```

You can add `; next` after every `p` assignment in the main body if you like but it won't affect the output, just improve the efficiency which would matter if your input was thousands of lines long.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you can't use `next` in a function. You have to place it after each function *call*:

```
    /KB?$/ { printpower($1, 10,  3); next; }
    /MB?$/ { printpower($1, 10,  6); next; }
    ...
```

But you can just let `awk` test the remaining patterns (no `next` anywhere) if you don't mind the extra CPU cycles. Note that the parentheses around `B` are redundant and I have removed them.

```
$ dehumanise 1000MiB 19Ki
1048576000
19456
```

Comment: I tried that as it seemed obvious, but it results in no output at all.

Comment: I installed gawk and overwrote macOS awk version. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You could use a control variable in your function and check the value of the variable to decide to use next in the main routine.

```awk
  # MAIN
      {
      myfunction(test)  
      if (result == 1) next  
      # result is not 1, just continue  
      # more statements  
      }  

      function myfunction(a) {  
        # default result is 0  
        result = 0  
        # some test  
        if ($1 ~ /searchterm/) {  
          result = 1  
        }  

      }
```